# NTLM authorization WCF in ASP.NET Core does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asp.net-core

I encountered with problem NTLM authorization
I have service which work on asp.net without any problems, but now I need to work with this service on asp.net core, and I can't pass authorization.

I configure binding like this:

```
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
        binding.OpenTimeout = binding.CloseTimeout = 
        binding.SendTimeout = binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20971520;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = binding.MaxBufferSize = 20971520;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength =
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength =
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead =
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2097152;

        binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
        //binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        binding.AllowCookies = false;
```

Then added

```
        ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = service.Login;
        ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = service.Password;
```

Then I do some request to service and get

> ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The
>   authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

I opened fiddler and compared two requests ( asp.net and core)
And I found difference in Authorization header, but password and login the same in config file.

ASP.NET :

Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4I**Y**ogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKADk4AAAADw==

Core :

Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4I**I**ogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKADk4AAAADw==

I tried to write custom behavior in order to put header from asp.net instead of core variant in BeforeSendRequest(), but in the second request client again send core variant of header and I again get the same message about NTLM

May be I try to find mistake in a wrong place?

Comment: This might be completely wrong but it looks like it is a case sensitive issue. The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme !! 'Ntlm' !!. The authentication header received from the server was !! 'NTLM' !!.

Comment: I thought about it, but I get the same message for example in asp.net if I set wrong password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out reason of this behavior. 
In asp.net I don't set Domain,  only login and password and it works.
But in asp dotnet core it does not work for me, I added Domain. And now it work in asp dotnet core too.

```
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential
    {
        UserName = service.Login,
        Password = service.Password,
        Domain = service.Domain
    };
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials;
```